# Windows 10 : Service seemingly not executing on boot even when set to Automatic (Delayed Start)

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

I have registered a custom service called `customService` with *Automatic (Delayed Start)* as its Startup Type option. It was created using [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/download) with the following command

```
nssm install customService
```

It runs a simple batch file, `customService.bat` containing two simple windows command

```
cd D:\To\Custom\Path
type NUL > 1.txt
```

What the service does is run this batch file which would create an empty text file, 1.txt in \To\Custom\Path folder.

**Problem**

When I *shutdown and boot up* my machine, no 1.txt is created. However, in services.msc, it shows `customService` status as Running. Why is this happening?

---

**What I have discovered**

1. When the problem occurs, in Event Logs > Windows logs > Application, there is no error produced. The last recorded log is from `MSSQLSERVER` service with the Level of Information and Event ID of 8128. It has been exactly 15 minutes passed.
2. In `services.msc` > `customService` Status shows Running. When I right-click it, I'm allowed at least 3 options: Stop, Pause, and Restart. The service runs successfully (i.e., 1.txt created) when I clicked `Restart`.
3. In `services.msc` > `customService` properties > Dependencies tab, it shows *no Dependencies*
4. I have absolutely no problems when I *restart* my computer ( i.e., 1.txt is created.)

**Windows Specs**

I have `Windows 10 Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.576)` as shown when running `winver` command. Also, I have all updates installed.

Answer (score 1):

How did you define the service?  [Documentation](http://nssm.cc/usage) suggests you should have a run commands like:

```
nssm set UT2003 Application C:\games\ut2003\System\UCC.exe
nssm set UT2003 AppDirectory C:\games\ut2003\System
```

(Substituting in the path to your batch file)

In any case, NSSM sounds like overkill here.  Why not just use Task Scheduler?

Comment: That is another way to do it. However, documentation also suggests the use of GUI. How is it different? I.e., when running `nssm install customService`, a GUI pops up enabling me to set Application path and AppDirectory.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for the suggestion to use Task Scheduler. It lead me to believe this is due to Log In issue after trying it out with Task Scheduler.

Comment: I agree with @ernie, NSSM isn't right tool here. Concept of service is continuously running program, such as web server for example. If you need to do just a single shot, it IMHO a task for Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is just a crude workaround that I hope can be useful to others, not a fix. The workaround is use Task Scheduler instead.*

I have deep suspicion this problem is due to User Account issues although *I don't have any concrete written evidence for that*

I arrived at this suspicion when I tried to use [Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to launch my .bat file instead of using a Service. When I set it to `Run on system startup`, after booting up, there was a Warning in History tab of my created task saying `Task Scheduler did not launch task because user "(NONE)" was not logged on when the launching conditions were met`. Hence the reason why I think this problem is somehow linked to User Account issues although I may be wrong because no such warning/error occur in Event logs when I used Services to launch my batch file.

So I set it to run `after logged on` and there have been no problems running this task on startup. I'm not sure if this kind of setting can also be set for Services. This could also be the reason why people tend to use the setting *Automatic (Delayed Start)*

Note that setting this task to run `after logged on` will make it run when you signed in having signed out. It will not run when you signed in after *locking your computer*,

Comment: If you want to run some task `on system startup` you need to create privileged user and setup him up in Task Scheduler as user how going to run this task. Well if computer isolated from wild internet and strange people, you can run your task as a SYSTEM user, but it really a bad idea if it isn't.